# Stating if a function being a contraction

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I have to state if a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a contraction on the interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ and say if it admits fixed points.

The function is $f(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  sin\frac{1}{x}\:if\: x\neq 0\\
                  0 \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:if\:x=0
                \end{array}
              \right.$

defined on $I = \mathbb{R}$.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Hint for the second question: look at the second case of your function.

Comment: Hint for the first question: $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ has infinitely-fast oscillations near the origin: i.e., points close on the $x-$axis that are "far apart" (at least far enough) in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not a contraction on $\mathbb{R}$ : in fact

$$1=\left |f \left (\frac{2}{\pi} \right)-f(0) \right |>\left |\frac{2}{\pi}-0 \right |=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Now, $\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right )-x$ is continuous in the interval $\left [\frac{1}{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}, \frac{1}{2\pi n-\frac{\pi}{2}}, \right ]$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But 
$$\sin \left (2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}\right )-\frac{1}{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}>0$$
And

$$\sin \left (2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2}\right )-\frac{1}{2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2}}<0$$

By the intermediate value  theorem there exists $\xi \in \left [\frac{1}{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}, \frac{1}{2\pi n-\frac{\pi}{2}}, \right ]$ such that $\xi=\sin \left ( \frac{1}{\xi} \right )$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$; hence, there are infinitely many fixed points of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$.